# Vodafone Webbook password

Tags: password-recovery

forgot the password on Vodafone webbook and followed the post to reset password but not able to go pass step 4.
[ZTE Vodafone WebBox W1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307144/vodafone-webbook/413965#413965)
The system does not want to mount to \dev\mmcblk0p3\mnt . Im not even able to cd to mmcblk0p3.

Can someone please assist with resetting the password or instructions on how to reinstall the software.

Comment: Be careful with your slashes. \ is *very* different from /

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the battery and flip a little switch behind the battery and then it would be in CD-ROM Discovery mode.

You can then access the root and reset the password after you pass the cd-rom stuff. (Pass through with NO, NO and then CONTINUE.

If i recall correctly, you then select the second last item on the menu and you would be able to mount 'mmcblk0p3' from there.

Good Luck, hope this helps...

Yusuf Ginnah
JHB 
SA